# xcode 6 compilation failure other linker flags ObjC

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang, linker-flags

I am tasked with maintaining a fairly large project that was originally developed for iOS5.

It has the following linker flags: `-force_load -ObjC -lc++`

What I get when trying to compile the project:

```
Ld /Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/textPlatform-brvpfnfcbedjwnamdiqbvrnbherf/Build/Intermediates/textPlatform.build/Debug-iphoneos/textPlatform\ Prod.build/Objects-normal/arm64/textPlatform\ Prod normal arm64
    cd /Users/dhomes/Desktop/CareChat/com.mozido.textPlatform.ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/textPlatform-brvpfnfcbedjwnamdiqbvrnbherf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/textPlatform-brvpfnfcbedjwnamdiqbvrnbherf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/textPlatform-brvpfnfcbedjwnamdiqbvrnbherf/Build/Intermediates/textPlatform.build/Debug-iphoneos/textPlatform\ Prod.build/Objects-normal/arm64/textPlatform\ Prod.LinkFileList -dead_strip -force_load -ObjC -lc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -licucore.A -lresolv -lxml2 -lstdc++.6 -lc++ -framework Accelerate -framework EventKit -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework AVFoundation -liconv -lstdc++ -framework AddressBookUI -framework MapKit -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreText -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz -lsqlite3 -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework Accounts -framework AdSupport -framework CoreBluetooth -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/textPlatform-brvpfnfcbedjwnamdiqbvrnbherf/Build/Intermediates/textPlatform.build/Debug-iphoneos/textPlatform\ Prod.build/Objects-normal/arm64/textPlatform\ Prod_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/textPlatform-brvpfnfcbedjwnamdiqbvrnbherf/Build/Intermediates/textPlatform.build/Debug-iphoneos/textPlatform\ Prod.build/Objects-normal/arm64/textPlatform\ Prod
```

**ld: file not found: -ObjC**
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Any help on this one? ANY help on this is highly appreciated

basically

Comment: As a side note you say you are using `-lc++` but I also see `-lstdc++` and `-lstdc++.6` in the linker command line.  That's a big problem.

Comment: @trojanfoe, thanks for the observation, it's not my code though, i was just trying to make it work.